# Starting springboot application from IntelliJ community edition

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, embedded-tomcat

How can we start a spring boot application in IntelliJ community edition. I don't see an embedded tomcat Included here. When I start the application from SpringBootApplication annotated class, getting the below messages only in the logger

> 2021-06-23 20:02:45.933  INFO 1086 --- [           main] r.e.r.RestapplicationApplication         : Starting RestapplicationApplication using Java 11.0.11 on Antonys-MBP.home with PID 1086 (/Users/robin/Documents/work/workspace/restapplication/target/classes started by robin in /Users/robin/Documents/work/workspace/restapplication)
> 2021-06-23 20:02:45.938  INFO 1086 --- [           main] r.e.r.RestapplicationApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> 2021-06-23 20:02:48.342  INFO 1086 --- [           main] r.e.r.RestapplicationApplication         : Started RestapplicationApplication in 3.621 seconds (JVM running for 4.888)

Please help on how can I start the application in tomcat and test in Community Editon of IntelliJ

Comment: It already started, just run the main method.

Answer (score 1):

> r.e.r.RestapplicationApplication : Started RestapplicationApplication
> in 3.621 seconds (JVM running for 4.888)

The above line tells you that the embedded tomcat has already started at default port 8080 ( unless you have overridden port in configuration). You can try hitting the application on the port.